# Confused about the implication operator in assertions

Tags: alloy

Signature `Test` has two fields, `a` and `b`:

```
sig Test {
    a: lone Value,
    b: lone Value
}

sig Value {}
```

Note that `a` and `b` may or may not have a value.

A `Test` is valid only if it satisfies this codependency: If `a` has a value, then `b` must also have a value:

```
pred valid (t: Test) {
    one t.a  => one t.b
}
```

I want to create an assertion and I expect the Alloy Analyzer to find counterexamples. The assertion is this: If `t: Test` is valid, then `t': Test` is also valid, where `t'` is identical to `t`, except `t'` does not have a value for `b`:

```
assert Valid_After_Removing_b_Value {
    all t, t': Test {  
         t'.a = t.a
         no t'.b 
         valid[t] => valid[t']
    }
}
```

I expect the Alloy Analyzer to generate counterexamples like this: `t` has a value for `a` and `b`. `t'` has a value for `a` but not for `b`. So, `t` is valid, but `t'` is not. But the Analyzer gives counterexamples like this: `t` has a value for `a` and `b` and `t'` has a value for `a` and `b`. I don't understand that. If `t` has a value for `a` and `b`, then `t` is valid. Likewise, if `t'` has a value for `a` and `b`, then `t'` is valid. How could that be a counterexample?

What is the right way to express the assertion? Again, my goal is to express this: I assert that if `t` is valid, then a slightly lesser version of `t` (e.g., `b` has no value) is also valid. That should generate counterexamples, due to the codependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your assertion should be:

```
assert Valid_After_Removing_b_Value {
    all t, t': Test {  
         (t'.a = t.a &&
          no t'.b &&
         valid[t]) => valid[t']
    }
}
```

In your original assertion, you assert three independent things. For example, every `t'` with a `b` would already be a counterexample.

Comment: Bingo! Fantastic! That works perfect. Thank you wmeyer!